# Where are api documentation and demo for JAVA OCR?

Tags: java, api, ocr

I want to use the JAVA OCR : http://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/
I can't find the api documentation and the demo. In the download file, I have only the jars.
Can somebody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can find demo code at [OCRScannerDemo](http://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/source/ci/master/tree/plugins/awt/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/javaocr/ocrPlugins/OCRDemo/OCRScannerDemo.java) for old api, for new api [new api demo](http://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/source/ci/master/tree/demos/)

About api javadoc you can generate it with maven.

To get source code : `git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/javaocr/source javaocr-source`